# Fatal error: Class ‘MagentoPycho_Lightboxes_Helper_Data’ not found in appMage.php on line 516

Tags: magento-1

I am facing problem after installing [jQuery Lightboxes (FancyBox, PiroBox etc.)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/jquery-lightboxes-fancybox-pirobox-etc.html)

Fatal error: Class ‘MagentoPycho_Lightboxes_Helper_Data’ not found in appMage.php on line 516

---

*[UPDATED]*

Some parameters in the *js/colorswatch/colorswatch.js  (line 34)* are undefined when Lightboxes are instaslled ( even if they are disabled ).

Here is my error message. in var\log\system.log:

> 2013-03-01T10:05:02+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object  in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\store\includes\src\Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data.php
>   on line 135 2013-03-01T10:05:02+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get
>   property of non-object  in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\store\includes\src\Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data.php
>   on line 135 2013-03-01T10:05:09+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined
>   variable: productId  in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\store\app\design\frontend\default\helloresponsive\template\catalog\product\compare\sidebar.phtml
>   on line 32 2013-03-01T10:05:17+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined
>   variable: productId  in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\store\app\design\frontend\default\helloresponsive\template\catalog\product\compare\sidebar.phtml
>   on line 32 2013-03-01T10:05:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined
>   variable: productId  in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\store\app\design\frontend\default\helloresponsive\template\catalog\product\compare\sidebar.phtml
>   on line 32

This function  $this->getGroups() is not returning anything.

Comment: yes. they are in the right place and the class is also present.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Now it is working fine. I cleared the cache and Run "Compilation Process".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure it's not your cache or compile.

Then check have `app/code/local/MagentoPycho/Lightboxes/Helper/Data.php` file in place and there's `MagentoPycho_Lightboxes_Helper_Data` class inside.

If the problem is still there it is possible that you have another (same extension in another scope) which uses that same group mame (in your case `lightboxes`).

Comment: But. I had installed "Colors Sizes and Materials Swatch PRO" in my project. Now it is not working.

Comment: First temporary disable cache and compilation. Then enable error logging and check if there are anything in your `var/log`.

Comment: Also it's quite possible that those two extensions are conflicting overriding the same class.

Comment: Tim, I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: It looks like jQuery/prototype conflict. Try running `jQuery.noConflict();`. If it will not help please create a new question, because this it not related to initial issue you had.

Comment: I took another [link](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)Lightbox 2[link]
and done coding manually.